# How to rollback a transaction with a catched exception?

Tags: java, jpa, jta

I have a Rest API and I want catch all exceptions to send a custom message for client when some error is thrown.

I catched the exceptions with try { ... } catch (Exception e) { ... } but, in these mode, the rollback doesn't execute and the data are persisted.

```
@POST
@Transactional
public Response add(Foo foo) {
    try {
        Foo add = this.service.add(foo);

        return Response.status(CREATED)
                .entity(add)
                .build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.status(BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity("Contact the support! Error: " + e.getMessage())
                .build();
    }
}
```

I want rollback the transaction because the data are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using `@Transactional` it's already taken care of. You don't have to do rollback on your own (it's a bit like try-with-resources). You would have to rollback transaction, when using explicitly [Transaction](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/transaction/Transaction.html) in `finally` clause of `try`.

Comment: OK! But, how I do it?

Comment: @essejoje just read the answer, `@Transactional` already rollbacks. You don't have to do anything

Comment: But when I catch the exception, the rollback doesn't run.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it works. Sorry, I assumed, that's controlled. You need to rethrow the error. If you want the return value, you would have to use `Transaction`. Here is how to do it: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged

Comment: Thank you very much! I thrown the WebApplicationException, that rollback the transaction and let me send the message for client.

Comment: @essejoje no problem, consider upvoting / marking as correct;)

Comment: throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(BAD_REQUEST).entity("Contact the support! Error: " + e.getMessage()).build());